# How can I remove the middle of a pandas group and keep the head and tail only?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
           Location         ID    Item      Qty     Time
(...)
42666           381  202546661  995820        1 06:55:07
42667           761  202547268  995820        1 07:12:44
42668           494  202546857  995822        1 06:58:30
42669           455  202546771  999810        1 06:56:52 <- head
42670           730  202547225  999810        1 07:11:57 <- to be deleted
42671           761  202547268  999810        1 07:13:04 <- tail
42672           494  202546857  999825        2 06:58:52
42673           424  202546723  999942        1 06:55:36 <- head
42674           487  202546848  999942        1 06:57:47 <- to be deleted
42675           514  202546891  999942        1 06:59:23 <- to be deleted
42676           587  202547004  999942        1 07:01:03 <- to be deleted
42677           654  202547101  999942        1 07:01:42 <- tail
(...)
```

I am trying to get the head and tail only and remove the rows in between so that is looks like this:

```
           Location         ID    Item      Qty     Time
(...)
42666           381  202546661  995820        1 06:55:07
42667           761  202547268  995820        1 07:12:44
42668           494  202546857  995822        1 06:58:30
42669           455  202546771  999810        1 06:56:52 <- head
42670           761  202547268  999810        1 07:13:04 <- tail
42671           494  202546857  999825        2 06:58:52
42672           424  202546723  999942        1 06:55:36 <- head
42673           654  202547101  999942        1 07:01:42 <- tail
(...)
```

How can I achieve this outcome?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) to keep the first and last samples within each group:

```
df = df.groupby('Item').nth([0,-1]).reset_index()

    Item   Location       ID    Qty    Time
0  995820       381  202546661    1  06:55:07
1  995820       761  202547268    1  07:12:44
2  995822       494  202546857    1  06:58:30
3  999810       455  202546771    1  06:56:52
4  999810       761  202547268    1  07:13:04
5  999825       494  202546857    2  06:58:52
6  999942       424  202546723    1  06:55:36
7  999942       654  202547101    1  07:01:42
```

Comment: I'm not having any success with this, it does not seem to be removing any rows from the df. Is my query clear enough?

Comment: No? I'm trying with your sample df, for me it is only keeping the first and last rows within each group. For instance for item `999810` the output contains 2 samples, in the input there are 3 @nikugan

Comment: Make sure you are reassigning the result, I updated JIC